# Accessibility under Android settings not opening in Samsung Galaxy Phone

Tags: android, adb, accessibility, settings

I uninstalled a ton of bloatware while setting up a new Samsung Galaxy phone using command `pm uninstall -k --user 0 <package-name>`. All went fine except that the 'Accessibility' section under Settings menu does not open and crashes repeatedly. Not sure which package to reinstall in order to fix it. I see the packages `com.samsung.accessibility` and `com.samsung.android.accessibility.talkback` are already installed and I did not even touched them.

Already tried restarting the device. Don't want to do a factory reset cause then I have to start cleaning all over again.

Will greatly appreciate any help. TIA

Answer (score 2):

Solved it!

`cmd package install-existing com.samsung.android.honeyboard`

Comment: I'd really like to know why `com.samsung.android.honeyboard` (which is the stock built-in Samsung Keyboard) _must_ be installed in order to open this one menu specifically. Everything else seems to work fine, except Accessibility won't open unless this keyboard is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use the ***-k*** before ***--user*** in **pm uninstall -k --user 0**

All that does is to prevent the system from deleting any associated data from the app, in case you want to reinstall it later without having to set everything up again.

For adb shell using Wireless Debugging method, the command should be like this :

**pm install-existing --user 0 com.samsung.android.honeyboard**

Comment: wait, there is no such thing as a problem with Codistan's **cmd package** thing. Sorry my bad..